# How do I raise a really big number to a really big power?

Tags: c#, pow, ulong

I have a `ulong` value that I need to raise to a high power, but `Math.Pow` does not successfully produce a correct output.

My c# code:

```
 ulong a = 9123456789;
 ulong b = (ulong)Math.Pow(a, 9999);
 Console.WriteLine(b);
```

The output to screen is 0. How can I perform this calculation and obtain a correct result?

Comment: Do you seriously think that 9123456789^9999 will fit in a ulong?

Comment: `Math.Pow` only works on doubles.

Comment: What could you possibly be doing with a number that big anyway?

Comment: [it's nearly 100,000 decimal digits long](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=9123456789%5E9999&dataset=)

Comment: Read the [MSDN for `Math.Pow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pow(v=vs.110).aspx), it tells you when it returns 0, such as when the number is larger than can fit in the data type. Some methods like to do things like throw exceptions for errors like this, this one just returns `0` instead.

Comment: Yes.I need 9123456789^9999 Mathematical operation

Comment: This is impossible ?

Comment: @TaGiAsadullazadeh Have you tried `BigInteger`?

Comment: @juharr not....

Comment: I'm intellectually curious as to the problem that requires raising a value to the 9999th power. Care to share? My worldview needs expanding.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram Math problems mainly like perfect number calculation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to compute that number, using the specialized `BigInteger` class. It's hopeless to try and do this with a `ushort`, which has a width of 16 bits.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Numerics;

public class Test 
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BigInteger a = 9123456789;
        BigInteger b = BigInteger.Pow(a, 9999);

        //Output this number if you're feeling lucky.
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
43056151396124937171542222696555900626431494491043369510338912076154406943108
..
8614367506747618876018379290109
```

By the way, you'd need 330,837 bits to store the result.

Comment: You need explicitly include the `System.Numerics.dll` in your project. Go in visual studio, right-click on "References" in side the project, go to "Assemblies", then search for `System.Numerics` and add a tick-mark next the name. That should include the dll and the code should compile.

Answer (score 0):

Look up for [BigInteger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx) if you're going to work with very big numbers.

Comment: @Great.And.Powerful.Oz Haha. Sorry about that, fixed it now. Thanks!